# adding months to a date in groovy is not working

Tags: groovy, timecategory

In the below code, only the year gets added to my date. the months are not getting added.

```
def calculateLicense(Date bd, int yr, int mon=0){
    use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
        Date licenseDate = bd + yr.years + mon.months
        println "License date:" + licenseDate.format('mm/dd/yyyy')
    }
```

Comment: Just to have it asked: your default there is addin 0 month.  You are not just hitting that case?

Comment: yr = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())
if (choice==2){
 println "Enter the expiry month:"
 mon = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())
 calculateLicense(bd,yr,mon)
}
else {
 calculateLicense(bd,yr)
}

Comment: i hit both cases where if i don't pass the mon parameter, it is defaulted to '0'

Answer (score 0):

The format you used here:

```
licenseDate.format('mm/dd/yyyy')
```

means `(minute in hour)/(day of month)/(year)`. It should be

```
licenseDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

instead, because `MM` stands for month in the year. Your code responsible for adding year and month is correct, you only missed formatting and displaying the date in correct format.

Take a look at below example:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def calculateLicense(Date bd, int yr, int mon = 0) {
  use(TimeCategory) {
    Date licenseDate = bd + yr.years + mon.months
    println "License date:" + licenseDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy')
  }
}

calculateLicense(Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2018-06-06"), 2, 3)
calculateLicense(Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2018-06-06"), 2)
```

Output:

```
License date:09/06/2020
License date:06/06/2020
```